# Executing a raw sql command needs always the schema + tablename in sql management studio

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity, sql-server-2012, ssms

When I am executing a SQL statement like:

```
Delete From [dbo].[User]
```

this works fine.

When I execute this statement also in my SQL Server 2012 Management Studio:

```
Delete From User
```

it does not work. This has never been an issue in former management studio version, but why now?

The database was created by Entity Framework code first approach.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Did you interpret the message at all?

Comment: work means the data inside the table got deleted. Not work means the query was not executed as there were errors.

Comment: **What were those errors?** Would you consider providing that information?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.